# Is "grapple hooking" a correct phrase?

Tags: phrases, verbs

I want to say "using a grapple hook" as a verb. In context it would be like "sprinting, jumping, grapple hooking"—but that doesn't sound right. Is it correct? If not, is there a way to say it as a verb?

Comment: Google suggests that "grappling hook" is the more normal usage, but I don't it can be easily verbed.  Perhaps you could try "sprinting, jumping, and flinging her grappling hook"..

Comment: @Thruston: I agree. Even if you *can* make a verb from a noun, it doesn't mean you should. "Verbing weirds language."

Comment: Could it be related to grapple tackle? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapple_tackle

Comment: @TimLymington: Doesn't mean you *shouldn't*, either. There's nothing wrong with *fly fishing*. Which by Thruston's logic would probably be *flying fishing*.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: [Grappling hooks](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grappling+hook) are nothing to do with wrestling tackles. I've only known them as used by dockers/stevedores for work (or murder, if I recall [Edge of the City](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050347/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) correctly), but presumably they can build a sport around the vicious-looking things.

Comment: Is your context real, or a simple example? "Sprinting, jumping, grappling (wrestling)" is a much more likely combination of activities than "sprinting, jumping, and grapple-hooking".

Comment: @Jim You obviously haven't played many computer games recently.

Comment: @Fumble: are you trolling rather than fly fishing? Or have you actually seen a *fly fish* recently?

Comment: @TimLymington: No-one has ever seen "a grapple" in the act of *hooking* either. My point is that the original compound noun is ***a hook*** (subtype ***grappling** hook*). The noun *hook* is verbified in the same way as the noun *fish* is verbified. So once we've identified *hook* as the relevant verb, that's the one we add *-ing* to in order to create the "gerund noun" *hooking*. And no-one would want *grappling hooking*, so the *grappling* component reverts to *grapple* to identify the subtype of hooking involved in this (to me, totally unknown) activity/sport/whatever.

Comment: @Fumble: At least I now see where we disagree.  Since, as you say, nobody would want 'grappling hooking', I would prefer 'throwing a grappling hook' (which is recorded) to 'grapple hooking' (which is not). Incidentally, I think you've misidentified the type of hook; this is an unpowered grapnel (which is why it has to be thrown) rather than a labourer's tool.

Comment: @TimLymington: I know nothing of "powered grapnels". I just know about [grappling/grapnel irons/hooks](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grappling+iron), such as sailors, dockers, and maybe warehousemen use. And I don't know the actual activity OP is referring to either. All I know is if he wants a gerund, he must form it from *hook*, not *grapple*.

Answer (score 2):

In a "composite verb" to mean *hooking with a grapple hook*, the verb component is *to **hook** [with something]*, so the present participle must be *grapple-**hooking***.

I can't actually find a written instance of OP's exact form, but here's

> [Rugby, however, had so grapple-hooked the Welsh psyche that, [blah blah].](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XfOBAAAAMAAJ&q=%22grapple%20hooked%22&dq=%22grapple%20hooked%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3SpSUb7iK6Pw0gWl7YDAAg&ved=0CFoQ6AEwCTgK)

...which illustrates the general principle (a verb is a verb is a verb). It's really a matter of style whether you include the hyphen or not, but I think most people would prefer it to be there.

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing out the all-too-common tendency to ignore what the actual verb is.